# Which one is correct ? ''feel it amazed or amazing''

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, exam-questions

> You will feel it _________(amaze) to see the wonderful view of the whole town from the mountain.

Which one is correct ? "feel it amazed" or "amazing". The answer is "amazing". Is that right?

Comment: Neither makes much sense to me. It should be "You'll *find* it amazing..." or "You'll feel amazing...". Using "You'll feel it amazingly..." is grammatically correct but doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: "Feel amazed" or "find it amazing" would be the most natural. Another poor textbook.